# Responsive Design: What to use as a reference for relative size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Currently working on my first highly responsive site. I've worked through a few basic tutorials about that topic, though I've often noticed that they rely on slightly older mobile devices and they switch the designs by `@media` depending on the screen size attributes.

Now we have mobile devices which have the same FullHD resolution on a 6" screen like on a 24" monitor... so that can impossibly work.

So what can I use to scale text and things like menus correctly? I'd like not to use percentage values absolutely everywhere.

My intuitive idea would be to compute a reference size of which I know that it has always the same size on the screen. Or at least something what can give me a hint of how to adjust the sizes.

I tried to used the "em" measurement in CSS for that by creating an element with this size and then measure it's height via Jquery, since from how I understood it, "em" is a browser-depending size.

Still the result is always 16px, no matter what browser I use...

So what type of relative size reference is usually used for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use http://getbootstrap.com/, that should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to try using the min-device-pixel-ration media query (have a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

If you have the same number of pixels on a 6" screen as you would normally get on a 24" monitor it is almost certainly going have a ration greater than 1 on the smaller screen. Otherwise it would be virtually impossible to read!

Comment: Ahh, hmm, yes, that looks very promising! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have differents units for relative length in CSS :

`em`    Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

`ex`    Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used)

`ch`    Relative to width of the "0" (zero)

`rem`   Relative to font-size of the root element

`vw`    Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport

`vh`    Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

`vmin`  Relative to 1% of viewport's smaller dimension

`vmax`  Relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension

`%`     Relative to parent

The `em` and `rem` units are practical in creating perfectly scalable layout!

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Thank you very much, but I knew most of those already.
Could you tell me quickly how to make anything scaleable with em and rem though?
Since that's just what I tried but while a text with height of "1em" looks readable on the desktop, it is faaar to tiny on a smartphone screen. And it's 16px high on both devices.
 
So I'd need a unit which gets rendered with more pixels, the higher the device resolution is...

Answer (score 0):

the default value for an em unit is 16px - however, you can reset this value to anything you want by changing it in the body tag.

```
body {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

So using that example 1em = 16px, 2em = 32px, 3em = 48px ect.

This website is a great resource for how to scale ems so you don't have to do the math: http://type-scale.com/

Keep in mind when using ems there is a compounding effect when using nested elements. So if you have a div with a font-size of 1em, inside of a div with a font-size of 2em, you will actually end up with a font size of 3em.

To prevent this you can either pay attention to your nesting, or use rem units. rem stands for root em and will always scale relative to the root element and ignore multiple nesting values.